# How not to trigger the Bootstrap tab click on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying not to trigger bootstrap tab click in asp.net. Here is my HTML

```
<div class="addNewTab">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li id="li1" class="deactiveLink"><a href="#tabBasicInfo" onclick="return getit();"
                            data-toggle="tab">Step 1: Details<span> </span></a></li>
    li id="li2" class="deactiveLink"><a href="#tabAdditionalInfo" onclick="return getit();"
                            data-toggle="tab">Step 2: Photos<span></span></a></li>
    <li id="li3" class="deactiveLink"><a href="#tabAdditionalFeature"
                            onclick="return getit();" data-toggle="tab">Step 3:Add. Info <span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="li4" class="deactiveLink"><a href="#tabPreview" onclick="return getit();"
                            data-toggle="tab">Step 4: Preview<span></span></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript function

```
    function getit() {
        return false;
    }
```

I have tried this in getit()

```
   $('.addNewTab >.nav-tabs > li:nth-child(5)').find('a').trigger('click');
```

I am new to Bootstrap therefore I am unable to do my task. I do not want to use divs for that. I want to use tab  which cannot be clicked. Am I missing something here in my code? What do I need to do?

Comment: Simply remove href from <a> tag and it will become unclickable

Comment: If you want to make it "unclickable" why use tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to bootstrap 3 docs http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs you can active the tabs either manually be javascript or by adding `data-toggle="tab"` or `data-toggle="pill"` on an element. 
So you can not add the `data-toggle="tab"` or `data-toggle="pill"` but rather active them with javascript when you need it.
As already mentioned in the comments you can remove the `href` from `<a>` elements to prevent browser's attemts to navigate to a given url on click, or assign onclick handler to these `a` elements and use `event.preventDefault()`